# How can I add an app to my ios app in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to add an open source ios app written in objective-c to my ios app.  What would be the best way to do that?  Shall I use multiple story board or I is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: you are trying to merge two apps?

Comment: i think that is not possible, you just import third party library on your app and using thats

Comment: I am trying to add a feature to my app which is already written as another app and it is open source.  I am going to merge it into my app by adding a button to main page which connects to the main page of second app. (Sort of sub app)

Comment: You can't add another app to an existing app. You could add source code, or files, or a library, or a project to a workspace. Maybe you're not using the correct term to refer to what you mean, so try and find out and be more precise with exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to add another app to my app.  I should probably add the source code separately and start with recreating the UI!